# Add event listener by class, pass ID as argument in JS

Tags: javascript, class, checkbox, addeventlistener

I have a grid set up of days of the week by times of the day, each slot on the grid is a checkbox for my site's users to indicate availability. Since this ends up being a large number of slots, I would like for the background color of the slot to change depending on whether it is checked or not, but again due to the large number of slots I don't want to have to add an event listener for each ID. Is it possible to add a single listener for the class and pass the ID of the clicked element so only its background is changed?

Comment: Read about "event delegation".

Comment: Are the checkbox already checked(loaded maybe via PHP) or do you have to check if they are? Sorry for the pun

Comment: By default they are unchecked, but after a user sets them once they're loaded from the database. I was able to initially set the backgrounds via Php, just couldn't figure out the JS to make it dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use event delegation to accomplish this, simple example

```
document.addEventListener('change', function(e){alert(e.target.id)});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/cCFxQ/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your checkboxes are the childNodes of your `<td>` elements, you can use this code:

```
var checkedList = document.getElementsByClassName('checked');
for(var i = 0; i < checkedList.length; i++) {
    var current = checkedList[i],
        parent = current.parentNode; //it is the td
    if (current.checked) parent.style.backgroundColor = 'color';
}
```

Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eU55k/)

If you want it to be completely dynamic, you should add an event listener as Musa said.

```
document.addEventListener('change', function(e){
    var current = e.target,
        parent = current.parentNode;
    if (current.checked) parent.style.backgroundColor = 'color';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

here a logic that should fix ur problem.
i will suggest of using a some framework "jquery" for easy work

```
var checkedList = document.getElementsByClassName('checkboxes');
checkedList.addEventListener('change', function(e){
   var node = e.target;
   if(node.checked){
      node.parentElement.style.background-color='grey';
   }else{
      node.parentElement.style.background-color='white';
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to solve the problem you had.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <style type="text/css">.lw {
  border: 1px solid red;
   font-size: 60px;
}
tr td{
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}</style>


<title>HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Start your code here -->
<div>
  <table class="gameboard">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="slot" id="One">x</td>
      <td class="slot" id="Two"></td>
      <td class="slot" id="Three"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="slot" id="Four"></td>
      <td class="slot" id="Five"></td>
      <td class="slot" id="Six"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="slot" id="Seven"></td>
      <td class="slot" id="Eight"></td>
      <td class="slot" id="Nine"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody></table> 
</div>  
<div>  
  <p id="titleOf" class="lw">Hello Weaver!</p>
</div>

<!-- End your code here -->

<script>/* Write JavaScript here */
var a = document.getElementById("titleText");
var b = document.getElementById("titleOf");
var c = document.getElementsByClassName("gameboard");
var piece = document.getElementsByClassName('slot');
var Gamelogic = {
    checkFirst:false,
    makeX: function(e){
        for(var i= 0; i< piece.length - 1; i++){
            if(e.path[i]){
                e.path[0].innerText = "X";
                e.path[0].style.backgroundColor = "green" ;
            console.log(e.path);
            console.log(e.path[0]);
            console.log(e.path[i]);
            }
            break;
        }
    }

};
c[0].addEventListener("click", Gamelogic.makeX); // if the table is clicked



</script>
</body>
```